# multiple insert to mongoose

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I'm using node js for my server side and angular and html for my client side.

I have insert data on my server side to mongoose. when I'm on the same page and want to insert new data to mongoose I have to restart the server again for it to work.

How can I write it in the code to restart it? or if there is a different way to clean my previous request?

```
  var savePersonal = new personal({
                email : myemail,
                Tags : mytags,
                Title: request.body.Title,
                Info: request.body.Info,
                Category: request.body.Category,
                file: "none",
                Recommendation:request.body.Recommendation,
                myDate:tempDate
              });
              savePersonal.save(function(error, result) {

                if (error) {
                  console.error(error);
                } else {
                  console.log("save");
                  request = "";
                  response.redirect('http://localhost:8080/getPrivateData.html');
                }
          })
```

Comment: show your code?

Comment: @Alex when I press again on the page that has the insert button - there server is stuck

Comment: if the issue were from this code above i guess it is the redirect thing , try to redirect to a route instead of html page for ex (response.redirect('/home'))

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to create new documents in db you must use update method, for example:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var personal = mongoose.models.personal;

personal.find({}, function(err, users){
    if(err) throw err;

    var data = {
                email : myemail,
                Tags : mytags,
                Title: request.body.Title,
                Info: request.body.Info,
                Category: request.body.Category,
                file: "none",
                Recommendation:request.body.Recommendation,
                myDate:tempDate
              };

    if(users.length)
       personal.create(data, function(err, results){...});
    else
       personal.update({_id: users[0]._id}, data, function(err, results){...});
})
```

This is very rough code but the main idea:
    1) Check is colletion empty
    2) if it's empty use save/create
    3) if it's not empty use update, but for update you must know _id of the document. I'm use id of the first element(users[0]._id).

Comment: hey! thanks for your answer! I do want to creat a new line - it just doesn't let me